# Animation from version 2.79b to 2.80 is not working

Tags: animation

I migrated to version 2.8, and the animation of a file is not working. The objects remained present. Since the animation is very long and months of working time, I wold like to recover such animation. Using Blender for artists, which is compatible to version 2.79b, the animation works normally.
The platform is Windows.
If necessary I send the file. Thanks

Comment: does this happen with this file only or with every file you try?

Comment: very good point. It is not working well with other animations

Comment: do you think I am doing something wrong???

Comment: how can I upload a file here? Is it possible?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is the recommended platform